# What does '(1) mean in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm still beginning my SystemVerilog but I came across a strange bit of code. I have some previously written files which I look at, compile and simulate, etc. One of the files always gives me an error, it has a code that looks like this:

```
assign next_empty_oh = empty_entries & ~(empty_entries - QUEUE_SIZE'(1));
```

Where `QUEUE_SIZE` is a predefined parameter. The error it gives is:

```
** Error: near "'": syntax error, unexpected '\'', expecting ';'
```

This is the first time I saw something like `'(1)` and I don't know what it means, and I don't know how to solve it. I'm using Questa for simulation.

Also about `always_comb` it gives me an error for invalid assignment inside it. The variables are defined as `output`, do they need to be `reg` or `logic` or something inside `always_comb` block to be assigned successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: `number'(expr)` means cast expr to the width defined by number. But you need to show more code including the declarations for everything. You last question should be asked a separate question with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59 but I still can't understand why this produces an error.
I'll post the other question separately.

The code is the open source Nyuzi processor. It can be found here | https://github.com/jbush001/NyuziProcessor

The code that produces this error can be found in files "hardware/core/tlb.sv", "hardware/core/l2_cache_pending_miss_cam.sv" and others. This particular code I posted is in the second file.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. It turns out that Questa 10.2c doesn't support it. I just tried it on ModelSim 10.4 and it worked and compiled with no errors. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was when `number` is a parameter, not just a numeric literal. This was a later enhancement to SystemVerilog.